# How to add icon into option menu?

Tags: android, optionmenu

I try to add icon into the option menu in my app. I  add icon attribute to the items But icons don't show.

```
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/exit"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_go"
        android:title="@string/exit"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/about_us"
        android:title="@string/about_us"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/help"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_go"
        android:title="@string/help"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/setting"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_go"
        android:title="@string/setting"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search_collection"
        android:icon="@drawable/search"
        android:title="@string/search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

I want my menu like this image.

[image]

Comment: Have you override the onPrepareOptionMenu Method and what have you done with android:showAsAction in xml ?

Comment: I don't override the onPrepareOptionMenu () Method.search_collection  item that is search view show in the action bar properly. I want another item's icon shown

Answer (score 1):

Use `android:showAsAction="always|withText"` in all your Items

```
   <item
        android:id="@+id/help"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_go"
        android:showAsAction="always|withText"
        android:title="@string/help"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **app:showAsAction="withText|always"**  in all your Items

```
  <item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Settings"
    app:showAsAction="withText|always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
```

I think in your application no sufficient place available for showing icon in the action bar..Rotate the emulator to landscape mode and see it is working or not ?

Comment: get error : Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token) for  this line :app:android:showAsAction="always|withText"  . I use my app in portrait mode always.

Comment: modified my answer..Try once

Comment: But  I use my app in portrait mode always.

Comment: In this way  all items shown in the action bar.But I want shown like up image.

Answer (score 0):

menu/menu_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_more"
    android:title="Main Menu"
    app:showAsAction="always">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_add"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_add"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:title="Add"
            app:showAsAction="never" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_remove"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_remove"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:title="remove"
            app:showAsAction="never" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

in Your MainActivity

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
    return true;
}
```

result

[image: result]

Comment: Hi, this doesn't provide a better answer than https://stackoverflow.com/a/33051094/2444099. If anything, I don't know which part of your bigger answer is the important part. Keep it simple. Please don't post duplicate answers, thank you.